# Searching name in multiple column and table

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am trying to search a name based on user query like
user(id,fname,lname,..)
business(id,name,address...)

I am writing hql query like

```
 String hql1 = "select count(*)  from  Client as cl  "
                    + "where cl.id=:bid "
                    + " and (cl.user.fname=:fname "
                    + " or cl.user.lname=:lname "
                    + " or cl.business.name=:name)";
            Query query1 = session.createQuery(hql1).setParameter("bid", bid)
                    .setParameter("fname", name + "%").setParameter("lname", name + "%").setParameter("name", name + "%");
            count = (Long) query1.uniqueResult();
```

I want to search whether user entered string is in fname or in lname or in name.
if fond in any where i have to fetch it.
but this is not fetching an data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  String hql1 = "select count(*)  from  Client as cl  "
                + "where cl.id=:bid "
                + " and (cl.user.fname like :fname "
                + " or cl.user.lname like :lname "
                + " or cl.business.name like :name)";
        Query query1 = session.createQuery(hql1).setParameter("bid", bid)
                .setParameter("fname", "%"+name + "%").setParameter("lname", "%"+name + "%").setParameter("name", "%"+name + "%");
        count = (Long) query1.uniqueResult();
```